# How can I further simplify (P ∨ ¬Q) → ¬(P ∨ Q)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify this equation, (it was more complex before the current point), but I'm stuck at this juncture, and am not sure where to go from here.

I've used De Morgan's Law and the Rule of Implication to get to this point.  I have a feeling looking at it that there is going to be a FALSE somewhere eventually, (I could be wrong), but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: ¬(P ∨ ¬Q)  ∨ ¬(P ∨ Q). Expand this to (¬P ^ Q)  v (¬P ^ ¬Q).  Can you now simplify this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
[(P\vee \neg Q)\rightarrow \neg(P\vee Q)]&\leftrightarrow [\neg (P\vee\neg Q) \vee \neg(P\vee Q)]\\
&\leftrightarrow[(\neg P \wedge \neg\neg Q)\vee (\neg P\wedge \neg Q)]\\
&\leftrightarrow[(\neg P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)]\\
&\leftrightarrow[\neg P \wedge (Q \vee \neg Q)]\\
&\leftrightarrow[\neg P]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Do an expression tree:

```
P Q C D E F G
0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

where:

```
C=NOT Q
D=P OR C
E=P OR Q
F=NOT E
G=D->F
```

Then your results (i.e. answer to G) should be quite simple to identify.